# PHP AND (&&), OR (||) prioritisation in conditional statements

Tags: php, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Could someone please explain whether or not it is possible to merge a  PHP If conditional statement (which contains say AND) with another OR one? And if so, how would one structure the syntax? Which takes priority?

For example, may aim is to achieve something like...

```
IF ($Var1 == "a" && $Var2 == "z"){
    //TRUE
        echo "HELLO WORLD";

        //<some code block here>
}

OR

IF ($Var3 == "5"){
    //TRUE
        echo "HELLO WORLD";

        //<some code block here>
}
```

but merged into one if conditional statement, so that I dont have to duplicate my block of code for two if statements (I'm aware I could put the code to be run in the IF statements in functions, but is there another way of doing it).

So in summary (NOTE, brackets below are purely added as a way to group items to indicate my intention for how the code should run/be processed):

```
(If Var1 = a AND Var2 = b) OR (if Var3 = 5), run block of code.
```

I'd be really grateful if some could help me out. I've been trying to find this out for months but have got nowhere. Apologies if this has already been discussed here on Stack Overflow, I tried searching but found nothing, although my search terms could've been wrong.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php && has higher precedence than ||

Comment: Thanks Salman A & Mark Baker.

Looking at the links provided, i see that && does indeed take precedence over ||

I think that I will use the brackets in my coding though as this enforces the priority i require. This should also make the code easier if any debugging is required at a later date.

Comment: Not only does it enforce priority, it should also improve readability

Comment: @MarkBaker: My thoughts exactly. Thanks for your help. One long turn query I had has been solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
if ( ($Var1 == "a" && $Var2 == "z") || ($Var3 == "5") ) {
```

Look carefully at the order of brackets. In just about every language I've come across, a bracket in a conditional indicate that the result of the expression in the bracket is to be evaluated as a whole. PHP is no exception - the first half is only true if both var1 = a and var2 = z, while the other half of the or is only true if var3 = 5. The complete is true when either [var1, var2] = [a,z] or [var3] = [z].

Comment: Wow, so my pseudo-code syntax was right? Excellent! I didnt even think of trying that, I'd just written it that way to try and illustrate what i was trying to do!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check this:

```
if (($Var1 == "a" && $Var2 == "z") || ($Var3 == "5")){
    //TRUE
        echo "HELLO WORLD";

        //<some code block here>
}
```

In fact, you don't need the extra parentheses, as && has a higher priority than ||. However, it helps let everything easy to track.

Comment: Thanks Korcholis,

Yes, as I commented above, I think I'll go with the parentheses route anyway as it makes the code easier to follow (i STILL consider myself relatively new to PHP).

Answer (score 3):

Use like this:-

```
if (($Var1 == "a" && $Var2 == "z") || ($Var3 == "5")) {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($Var1 == 'a' && $Var2 == 'b' || $Var3 == 5)
{ 
//run block of code.
}
```